# How can I get my USB-C Ethernet adaptor to work on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: networking, 17.10, ethernet, realtek

I have no clue on how to get started (I'm not an expert Linux user), but from the research I made people report this issue by showing their `syslog` output. Here is mine:

```
[   37.776184] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   37.921014] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0610
[   37.921020] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   37.921024] usb 1-3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[   37.921027] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
[   37.922385] hub 1-3:1.0: USB hub found
[   37.924065] hub 1-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[   38.036247] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   38.059830] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0612
[   38.059835] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   38.059839] usb 2-3: Product: USB3.0 Hub
[   38.059842] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
[   38.062473] hub 2-3:1.0: USB hub found
[   38.062827] hub 2-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[   38.904259] usb 2-3.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   38.925001] usb 2-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153
[   38.925007] usb 2-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[   38.925011] usb 2-3.1: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[   38.925014] usb 2-3.1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[   38.925017] usb 2-3.1: SerialNumber: 000001000000
[   39.777550] usb 1-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
libinput error: libinput bug: timer: offset negative (-30854)
[   43.996238] usb 2-3.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[   44.000181] usb 2-3.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.1"
bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service'
```

Please, what should I do next?

As requested by @chili555, here is the output `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58e6 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output for `lsmod`:

```
r8152                  57344  0
mii                    16384  2 usbnet,r8152
```

Output for `dmesg`:

```
[    8.163559] r8152 2-3.1:2.0: Unknown version 0x0000
[    8.170641] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
```

Also the Ethernet interface isn't showing:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3086  bytes 303137 (303.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3086  bytes 303137 (303.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.26  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fda0:8d16:89c3:fc00:e49a:863b:d6e2:86ae  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::b2bf:16eb:35f3:40ee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fda0:8d16:89c3:fc00:11f4:4de3:5c3e:ef9d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 90:61:ae:6c:53:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 89776  bytes 82124598 (82.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 40081  bytes 5131880 (5.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

@shadowbq Here's the output for

```
modinfo /lib/modules/4.*-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/r8152.ko |grep version
```

:

```
version:        v1.09.9
srcversion:     EFE9F0107512003CA9626F7
version:        v1.09.9
srcversion:     EFE9F0107512003CA9626F7
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: @chili555 thanks for replying. I have updated my post.

Comment: Your device is covered by the driver `r8152` in 17.10. Does it load? `lsmod | grep r8152` Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep r8152` Does it work plugged into another USB port?

Comment: @chili555 I have updated my post again. What do the outputs suggest?

Comment: Quick check: Are you plugged into a powered onboard usb-c port or is that an external usb-c hub, which may require additional power?

Comment: @shadowbq I'm plugged into a powered onboard usb-c.. The adaptor perfectly works on my windows partition.

Comment: what is the actual make model serial?

Comment: There have been a few bugs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1586195 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1622322 reported with the realtek usb3 driver.. how new is your Kernel? https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/usb/r8152.c

Comment: post update with  'modinfo /lib/modules/4.*-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/r8152.ko |grep version'

Comment: Does it work plugged into a different USB port?

Comment: @shadowbq I might have to boot windows to be able to get the serial.. How new is my kernerl? 4.13.0-25-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP x86_64

Comment: @chili555 unfortunately that's the only type-c port that I have.

Comment: kernel 4.13.0.25 uses 'version:  v1.09.9' of the driver. This is the latest available driver. Either its discovering the wrong device, a new chip, or there is a problem with your connector/wire

Comment: End of the road.. create a ticket with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a chat session, we tried a number of things but finally discovered that the installation of a mainline kernel version 4.15 from here solved the issue: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/